# Resource Could Not Be Found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am creating a website in ASP.NET MVC3. My problem is that I am getting a "Resource Could Not Be Found" error when the file referenced appears to be in the correct location.

This is the exact error message:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
The resource cannot be found. 
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 
Requested URL: /Views/Product/Index.cshtml
```

The thing is, there is an Index.cshtml in /Views/Product.

This is an excerpt from my Global.asax:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Product", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

Resolution:
The issue was that I had set Index.cshtml as the "start page" by right clicking and choosing "Set as Start Page". After typing the URL manually per nemesv's suggestion and seeing that everything worked, I went into the project settings and changed Web->Start Action to "Current Page".

Comment: Do you have a ProductController class? Does it implement the Index() method?

Comment: what url did u request when u got the error?

Comment: usually in a mvc(ish) web application a resource is depicted by a controller and by resource not found there is 99% chance that the ProductController is absent as pointed out by @Pete

Comment: @Pete Yes I have a ProductController class

Comment: You are requesting the wrong url. It should be `/Product/Index`

Comment: @apclary, i strongly recommend a MVC tutorial

Comment: @DaveA All of this code is from an MVC tutorial

Comment: @apclary, I recommend u either re-watch/read that tutorial or flush it. They have not explained the fundamentals of MVC

Comment: @nemesv Your suggestion works. The issue was that I had Index.cshtml set as "start page".

Answer (score 1):

You requested for `/Views/Product/Index.cshtml`, which is wrong. You must create a `ProductController` class with an `Index` method:

```
public class ProductController : Controller
{
    public void Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

and then request for `localhost:yourport/` to get the index for product controller as you defined it in your routes (or just `/Product/Index`).

Comment: I have a ProductController class with an Index() method.